# How to filter out Pandas DataFrame rows by group

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

I am trying to pull out duplicate quarters for each group under the Ticker column.  There should be just four quarters (Q1, Q2, Q3, Q4) per Fiscal Year for each Ticker group, as determined by the Month Day column.  Quarters are defined as either scheme: `A = {'Q1': '03-31', 'Q2': '06-30', 'Q3': '09-30', 'Q4': '12-31'}` or `B = {'Q1': '04-30', 'Q2': '07-31', 'Q3': '10-31', 'Q4': '01-31'}`.  The logic needs to:

1. Group by Ticker
2. Determine which quarter scheme to use per Ticker based on whether A scheme or B scheme has greater entries / representation
3. Filter out the quarter rows which do not belong to the correct scheme.

```
import pandas as pd
data = {'Ticker': ['AAL']*10+['TGT']*10,
        'Month Day': ['03-31', '06-30', '09-30', '12-31', '01-31', '03-31', '06-30', '07-31', '09-30', '12-31',
                      '04-30', '07-31', '10-31', '12-31', '01-31', '03-31', '04-30', '07-31', '10-31', '01-31'],
        'Fiscal Year': ['2017', '2017', '2017', '2017', '2017', '2018', '2018', '2018', '2018', '2018',
                        '2017', '2017', '2017', '2017', '2017', '2018', '2018', '2018', '2018', '2018'],
        'Quarter': ['Q1', 'Q2', 'Q3', 'Q4', 'Q4', 'Q1', 'Q2', 'Q2', 'Q3', 'Q4',
                    'Q1', 'Q2', 'Q3', 'Q4', 'Q4', 'Q1', 'Q1', 'Q2', 'Q3', 'Q4']}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

Ticker  Month Day   Fiscal Year Quarter Value
0   AAL 03-31       2017        Q1      0.10
1   AAL 06-30       2017        Q2      0.10
2   AAL 09-30       2017        Q3      0.10
3   AAL 12-31       2017        Q4      0.10
4   AAL 01-31       2017        Q4      0.10 *Filter out
5   AAL 03-31       2018        Q1      0.10
6   AAL 06-30       2018        Q2      0.10
7   AAL 07-31       2018        Q2      0.10 *Filter out
8   AAL 09-30       2018        Q3      0.10
9   AAL 12-31       2018        Q4      0.10
10  TGT 04-30       2017        Q1      0.60
11  TGT 07-31       2017        Q2      0.60
12  TGT 10-31       2017        Q3      0.60
13  TGT 12-31       2017        Q4      0.60 *Filter out
14  TGT 01-31       2017        Q4      0.60
15  TGT 03-31       2018        Q1      0.75 *Filter out
16  TGT 04-30       2018        Q1      0.75
17  TGT 07-31       2018        Q2      0.75
18  TGT 10-31       2018        Q3      0.75
19  TGT 01-31       2018        Q4      0.75
    ...             ...         ...     ...
```

Output should look like this:

```
    Ticker  Month Day   Fiscal Year Quarter Value
0   AAL     03-31       2017        Q1      0.10
1   AAL     06-30       2017        Q2      0.10
2   AAL     09-30       2017        Q3      0.10
3   AAL     12-31       2017        Q4      0.10
4   AAL     03-31       2018        Q1      0.10
5   AAL     06-30       2018        Q2      0.10
6   AAL     09-30       2018        Q3      0.10
7   AAL     12-31       2018        Q4      0.10
8   TGT     04-30       2017        Q1      0.60
9   TGT     07-31       2017        Q2      0.60
10  TGT     10-31       2017        Q3      0.60
11  TGT     01-31       2017        Q4      0.60
12  TGT     04-30       2018        Q1      0.75
13  TGT     07-31       2018        Q1      0.75
14  TGT     10-31       2018        Q3      0.75
15  TGT     01-31       2018        Q4      0.75
```

Comment: Thanks for the code that initializes the dataframe, it helps! Do you have a first attempt at solving the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a suggestion in case you haven't found a solution yet:

With the sample frame provided (note: there's no `Value` column in it) and

```
A = {'Q1': '03-31', 'Q2': '06-30', 'Q3': '09-30', 'Q4': '12-31'}
```

this

```
df['Scheme'] = 'A'
df['Scheme'].where(df['Month Day'].str.match(r'|'.join(A.values())), 'B', inplace=True)

df_choice = (df.groupby('Ticker')
               .agg(As = pd.NamedAgg(column='Scheme',
                                     aggfunc=lambda c: (c == 'A').sum()),
                    Bs = pd.NamedAgg(column='Scheme',
                                     aggfunc=lambda c: (c == 'B').sum())))
df_choice['Choice'] = 'A'
df_choice['Choice'].where(df_choice['Bs'] < df_choice['As'], 'B', inplace=True)

df = df.merge(df_choice['Choice'], on='Ticker', how='left')
df = (df[df['Scheme'] == df['Choice']].reset_index(drop=True)
                                      .drop(['Scheme', 'Choice'], axis='columns'))
```

produces the following result

```
   Ticker Month Day Fiscal Year Quarter
0     AAL     03-31        2017      Q1
1     AAL     06-30        2017      Q2
2     AAL     09-30        2017      Q3
3     AAL     12-31        2017      Q4
4     AAL     03-31        2018      Q1
5     AAL     06-30        2018      Q2
6     AAL     09-30        2018      Q3
7     AAL     12-31        2018      Q4
8     TGT     04-30        2017      Q1
9     TGT     07-31        2017      Q2
10    TGT     10-31        2017      Q3
11    TGT     01-31        2017      Q4
12    TGT     04-30        2018      Q1
13    TGT     07-31        2018      Q2
14    TGT     10-31        2018      Q3
15    TGT     01-31        2018      Q4
```

which seems to be your desired output?

Some illustrations:

After adding the `Scheme` column `df` looks like

```
   Ticker Month Day Fiscal Year Quarter Scheme
0     AAL     03-31        2017      Q1      A
1     AAL     06-30        2017      Q2      A
2     AAL     09-30        2017      Q3      A
3     AAL     12-31        2017      Q4      A
4     AAL     01-31        2017      Q4      B
5     AAL     03-31        2018      Q1      A
6     AAL     06-30        2018      Q2      A
7     AAL     07-31        2018      Q2      B
8     AAL     09-30        2018      Q3      A
9     AAL     12-31        2018      Q4      A
10    TGT     04-30        2017      Q1      B
11    TGT     07-31        2017      Q2      B
12    TGT     10-31        2017      Q3      B
13    TGT     12-31        2017      Q4      A
14    TGT     01-31        2017      Q4      B
15    TGT     03-31        2018      Q1      A
16    TGT     04-30        2018      Q1      B
17    TGT     07-31        2018      Q2      B
18    TGT     10-31        2018      Q3      B
19    TGT     01-31        2018      Q4      B
```

`df_choice` looks like

```
        As  Bs Choice
Ticker               
AAL      8   2      A
TGT      2   8      B
```

**But**: My impression is that the problem isn't fully specified: What happens in step 2 if there's a tie?

Comment: Perfect! That solves it.  As for the tie, it's unlikely in this problem, but in that case, we should default to Scheme A.